# Remove duplicate object from QList

Tags: c++, qt, list, qlist

I have a `QList<MyData>`, where `MyData` have 2 member, `int id` (unique) and `QString name`. I want to remove all duplicate entries based on `name`, and that entry must the highest `id` between other object that having the same `name`. Any suggestion of how to doing it in the fastest way? Performance is a very important factor here.

Some of my idea after Google-ed for the whole day:

- `qStableSort()` it based on id (descending), then loop through the `QList`, then for each entry, copy the entry to another new `QList` when the `name` is not exist on the new `QList`
- use `QList::toSet` (which remove all duplicate entry), and provide operator==() and a qHash() implementation based on `name`, but the unique entry may not have the highest id
- use `std::list::unique`, but I'm not sure how it works.

Comment: Using the standard C++ libraries functionality (either `std::list::unique` or the general `std::unique` function) means you have to copy the data to a standard container, and then copy them back to the `QList`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::list::unique`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/unique/) can take as argument a function with the following properties:

> Binary predicate that, taking two values of the same type than those
>   contained in the  list, returns true to remove the element passed as
>   first argument from the container, and false otherwise.
>       This shall be a function pointer or a function object.

So in your case you could use the folllowing function:

```
bool shouldRemove(MyData first, MyData second)
{
    // remove only if they have the same name and the first id
    // is smaller than the second one 
    return ( first.name == second.name && 
             first.id <= second.id ); 
}
```

To call it simply do,

```
std::list<MyData> myList = qlist.toStdList();
myList.unique(shouldRemove)
```

Notice that you need to sort first the `std::list`

**Edit**

It seems that you can use `std::unique` with `Qt containers` (if `Qt` is built with STL support). So in this case you could do the following:

```
// lessThan is a function that sorts first by name and then by id
qSort(qList.begin(), qList.end(), lessThan );
QList<MyData>::iterator it = std::unique (qList.begin(), qList.end(), shouldRemove);
qList.erase(it, qList.end());
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
QList<MyData> theList = ...;

QHash<QString, int> nameToIdMap;

for (const MyData& element : theList) {

    auto iter = nameToIdMap.find(element.name);
    if (iter != nameToIdMap.end() && iter.second > element.id) {
        // If item exists in map (name already occured) and the ID is 
        // bigger than in the current element, just skip the current element.
        continue;
    }

    // Otherwise, insert/overwrite it in the map.
    nameToIdMap[element.name] = element.id;
});

// nameToIdMap should now map unique names to highest IDs. If desired,
// you could copy it back into a new list by iterating over the map's entries
// and creating new MyData elements accordingly.
```

The advantage of this, in my eyes: You don't have to convert the list to a `std`-container and back, and if you find a way to continue working with the `QMap` instead of a `QList`, you will only have to iterate once over the initial list. And `QHash` will give you amortized `O(1)` lookup complexity.

Edit: Changed to `QHash`.

Comment: This is a nice idea too but I missed out 1 important point in my question: I actually have more than 2 members in `MyData`. My bad :(

Comment: That's not much of a problem: Just use a `QHash<QString, MyData>`, and then change the `if`-statement's second condition to: `iter.second.id > element.id`. Or maybe put `MyData*` into the QHash, to avoid copying all the MyDatas.

Comment: +1: cool for syntax! I have to switch to the new standard as soon as possible :-)

Answer (score 0):

I did this by STL-containers, but I think it's not very hard to convert it to Qt-containers

## include

```
#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct MyData {
    int id;
    std::string name;
};

struct MyDataSortComparator {
    bool operator()( const MyData & left, const MyData & right ) {
        if ( left.name < right.name ) {
            return true;
        }
        else if ( left.name > right.name ) {
            return false;
        }
        return left.id > right.id;
    }
};

struct MyDataSetComparator {
    bool operator()( const MyData & left, const MyData & right ) {
        return left.name < right.name;
    }
};


int main() {
    std::list< MyData > theList = {
        { 1, "Dickson" },
        { 2, "Dickson" },
        { 3, "Dickson" },
        { 2, "borisbn" },
        { 1, "borisbn" }
    };
    std::set< MyData, MyDataSetComparator > theSet;
    theList.sort( MyDataSortComparator() );
    std::for_each( theList.begin(), theList.end(), []( const MyData & data ) {
        std::cout << data.id << ", " << data.name << std::endl;
    } );
    std::for_each( theList.begin(), theList.end(), [&theSet]( const MyData & data ) {
        theSet.insert( data );
    } );
    std::cout << "-------------------" << std::endl;
    std::for_each( theSet.begin(), theSet.end(), []( const MyData & data ) {
        std::cout << data.id << ", " << data.name << std::endl;
    } );
}
```

http://liveworkspace.org/code/wOFnM$5

Comment: You're already using lambdas - why not for the sorting and set comparison?

Comment: @lethal-guitar, I do not like long-length lambdas, that's why I didn't use it in sort. In other hand I don't know how to use lambda in set definition. Could you tell me how to declare `theSet` in my example by lambda ? Thanks

Comment: Ok, apparently it's not possible in the set definition.. too bad, I like using lambdas for everything..